# How to create and apply texture to object in Qt3D with C++ or Python?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt3d

I am struggling to create and apply basic texture in Qt. I am trying to use `QDiffuseSpecularMaterial Class` but its maps are of `QVariant` type. I suppose I should use `QAbstractTexture Class` to load the textures and then convert them to `QVariant` somehow. Problem is that `QAbstractTexture Class` doesn't have any method that loads the texture. There is an `addTextureImage` method but its argument is `QAbstractTextureImage Class` that still doesn't have any load method. Even if I could load the textures somehow I have no idea how to convert them to `QVariant`. Does anyone know how to create and apply any basic image to the any basic 3D object? Is it possible to use `QImage` or `QPixmap` and convert them to Textures or `QVariant` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. The `QVariants` of `QDiffuseSpecularMaterial` are either a plain color or a texture, according to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qdiffusespecularmaterial.html#diffuse-prop).

Now, if you want to provide a texture, you have to use [`QTexture2D`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qtexture2d.html) (I assume you want to provide a 2D image) which inherits from `QAbstractTexture`. To actually make `QTexture2D` use your textures, you have to use `addTextureImage` (a function defined in `QAbstractTexture`). `addTextureImage` accepts [`QAbstractTextureImages`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qabstracttextureimage.html). The classes `QPaintedTextureImage` and `QTextureImage` both inhert from `QAbstractTextureImage` - using the former, you can manually paint a texture using `QPainter`, using the latter you can provide the URL to your texture file.

This is an example from [a project I forked](https://github.com/florianblume/simpleqml3d):

```
Entity {
    id: root

    Texture2D{
        id: texture
        TextureImage {
            source: "qrc:/man.png"
        }
    }

    RenderableEntity{
        id: chest
        source: "qrc:/man.obj"

        material: DiffuseMapMaterial {
            id: material
            diffuse:  texture
            specular: Qt.rgba( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 )
            shininess: 2.0
        }
    }
}
```